# Retain div state after back button pressed on browser

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel

Scenario - I am developing a laravel framework based website where user can add products to cart, when they add product to cart, I set opacity of that product's div to "0.3" (Somewhat less visible) in a way that user get to know which products has been added to cart without going on cart page to check it. Also, I use ajax lazyload which gets 6 products when user scrolls down the window. Also when user clicks on product I redirect them to product page where they can see the details of the product (like ecommerce)

Now the question is when user adds some products to cart and then opens up a product to check details, and then click browser back button to come back to product list page, selected items on that page are no longer selected (which means opacity is set to default although that product is added to cart). 
Please consider that I use lazyload to render more and more products on window scroll.

Things I tried - I have a session which stores all the cart products. I added code to my product list page that if product is added to cart, make opacity as 0.3 . But to get this result user have to click refresh button when he gets back to product list page.

Comment: "But to get this result user have to click refresh button when he gets back to product list page." Why? If products are in sessions (which I would avoid, maybe cookies is a better approach) you should be able to mark the selected products as faded inside the page logic?

Comment: Thanks for the response, but i dont want to use cookie because it has many things which I cannot control, for ex. if user blocks the cookies or deletes. Anyways I found solution for my problem.

Solutions : I created SetInterval Ajax function to get current products which I have in session and used that to change opacity of a product div. so now though i have a lazyload I can set product's opacity as I need.

Answer (score 0):

Solutions: I created SetInterval Ajax function to get current products which I have in session and used that to change opacity of a product div. so now though i have a lazyload I can set product's opacity as I need.

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function()
 {
    var refreshId = setInterval( function() 
    {
        $.ajax({
           url: '/products/state',
           type: "POST",
           success: function(data)
           {    
               if(data == 0)
               {

               }
               else
               {
                   $.each(data, function(key, value) 
                   {
                       $('#product_box_'+value).attr('style','opacity: 0.3');
                   });
               }
           } 
       });
   }, 500);

});
```